# how to resolve Symbol's value as variable is void when using ledger-mode

Tags: debugging, ledger

I am trying to setup a workflow wherein I generate Ledger files from different record files.  Typically I like to view them in ledger mode after cleaning but if I make a change to the conversion, then I have to revert the file, reenable ledger mode and then run the clean operation.  I tried making a function to do this for me, but I am encountering an error that I don't understand.  Below is the function as written in my initialize code:

```
(use-package ledger-mode
  :init
  :config
  (defun ledger-revert ()
    (interactive)
    (if not (eq major-mode 'ledger-mode)
      (ledger-mode))
    (revert-buffer t t t)
    (ledger-mode-clean-buffer)))
```

when I try to run the function to revert a ledger journal file I get:

```
>>> Symbol's value as variable is void: not
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Replacing `not (eq major-mode 'ledger-mode)` with `(not (eq major-mode 'ledger-mode))` would be a start. To help yourself here, you might want to read the *Intro to Emacs Lisp* manual (`C-h i`), or another introduction to Lisp, about symbols, variables, and functions in Lisp.

Comment: @Drew, thanks very much, and the tip for RTFM I suppose is always a good one to follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a set of parentheses.

The line

```
(if not (eq major-mode 'ledger-mode)
  (ledger-mode))
```

should be

```
(if (not (eq major-mode 'ledger-mode))
  (ledger-mode))
```

To quote [An Introduction to Programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Summary.html#Summary)<sup>1</sup>,

> When you evaluate a list, the Lisp interpreter looks at the first
> symbol in the list and then at the function definition bound to that
> symbol. Then the instructions in the function definition are carried
> out.

Without the parentheses around `not`, the symbol `not` it is interpreted as the first argument of the `if` function.  Since `not` has not been assigned a value, it's value is [void](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Void-Variables.html), hence the error message.

Emacs has a lot of tools to help you write Lisp<sup>2</sup>.  A simple one is `show-paren-mode`.  It will highlight matching pairs of parens:

[image]

You can enable `show-paren-mode` at startup by putting the following in your `init.el`:

```
(show-paren-mode 1)
```

---

<sup>1</sup>[An Introduction to programming in Emacs Lisp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/eintr.html) is typically bundled with Emacs and can be found using `C-h i`.  If you're running Debian, it's [packaged separately](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/emacs25-common-non-dfsg).

<sup>2</sup>Built-in or 3rd party: electric-pair-mode, autopair.el, smart-parens.el, lispy, paredit, et cetera.